# UPDATE data not getting in php file?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, updates

When i tried to UPDATE / PUT fields from  iOS to PHP server and am not getting these value over there.

this is my iOS Code

```
NSString *url=@"http://example.com/project/php/basicinfo.php";


    NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=%@&mname=%@&lname=%@&email=%@&country=%@&city=%@&dob=%@&role=%@",firstNameCell.fname.text ,mnameCell.mname.text,lnameCell.lname.text,emailCell.email.text,[countryCell.country currentTitle],cityCell.city.text,[dobCell.dob currentTitle],@"Model"];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringData);
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"UPDATE"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When i `echo`  in PHP its coming as empty.

Pls help me

This is the receiving response

```
 Did Receive Response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14ef17e40> { URL: http://example.com/project/php/basicinfo.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:15:40 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11";
} }
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";
$charset="UTF8";
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$mname=$_POST['mname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$role=$_POST['role'];
   echo $name;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_close($link);

   echo $email;
    $sql="UPDATE `basicinfo` SET `fname`='$fname',`mname`='$mname',`lname`='$lname',`email`='$email',`country`='$country',`city`='$city',`dob`='$dob',`role`='$role' WHERE `email`='$email'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  //  echo $email;
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
    //printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));
}

?>
```

Comment: show your php code...

Comment: @MarcBplease check updated code

Comment: $_POST is only populated when PHP sees the POST verb. You're doing an HTTP update, so $_POST will be empty. not even sure how to get `UPDATE` data in PHP. maybe reading it raw from `php://input`?

Comment: You should execute your transaction, a query retrives data.

Comment: should i user $_UPDATE ?

Comment: $_UPDATE does not even exist.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: got it..POST valeu from here and update in php

Comment: @MarcB you can add that as answer ..

Answer (score 0):

if you use UPDATE HTTP method to call your script $_POST won't work.

You can do something like that:

```
 $rest = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if(isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
        $content_type = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
    }

if ($rest=="PUT") {

$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
            parse_str($body, $parsed);
            switch ($content_type) 
            {
                case "application/json":
                   // do stuff
                    break;
                case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
                    // do stuff
                     break;
            }
            break;
        }


}
```

Or use POST